# How to fix toc hyperlink anchor scroll location in azure wikis (when there exist duplicate anchor - example: sub-topic)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

Below is my wiki content:

```
[[_TOC_]]

#Topic 1
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x

##Sub-Topic 1
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x

#Topic 2
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x

##Sub-Topic 1
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
```

On the page preview, in the toc section (top of the page), if I select Sub-Topic 1 hyperlink under the Topic 2, then the page scrolls to Topic 1's Sub-Topic 1. I expect that it should scroll to Topic 2's Sub-Topic 1. How can I fix this?

There seem to be open question about this with no response from Microsoft:

1. https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/360477/wiki-toc-duplicate-from-same-anchor.html
2. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/762156/wiki-anchor-links.html
3. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/783868/wiki-anchor-links-connect-to-the-correct-title.html

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here. In addition, you could also vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there, so product team would provide the updates if they view it. We will also help you vote it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

At present, this is a flaw in the design, and this is how it has been since anchor tags were introduced.

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#anchor-links) we can know that :

> Within Markdown files, anchor IDs are assigned to all headings when
>   rendered as HTML. The ID is the **heading text**.

So, if you give the sub-topics the same name , which will cause them to have the same id, which will cause the error when scrolling.

As you see , until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/783868/wiki-anchor-links-connect-to-the-correct-title.html) exist in it. You can comment and vote it there, so product team would provide the updates if they view it. I will also help you vote it. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Comment: How else can we re-write to format sub topics? Is there any alternative

Comment: AFAIK, there should be no other format. You can also refer to the document in the above answer to know the Syntax guidance for basic Markdown usage.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but if you add them as links, you can get the expected behavior.

Some drawbacks:

1. need to be sure that the text is unique
2. the link this produces will be broken if clicked
3. the text appears red on some platforms

Ex:

```
    ## [**Sub-Topic 1**](#04)
    ## [**Sub-Topic 1**](#03)
    ## [**Sub-Topic 1**](#02)
    ## [**Sub-Topic 1**](#01)
    ## [**Sub-Topic 1**](#00)
```